# FFMpeg Join mp4 Files Without Re-encoding but Keep Original Frame Rate

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I tried adding the `-vsync vfr` as a post suggested on https://superuser.com/a/1514949/1348487 but the original frame rate is not kept.

find *.mp4 | sed 's:\ :\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > list.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -vsync vfr -c copy output.mp4; rm list.txt

Original frame rate: 29.970000
Frame rate after joining: 29.969974

Any idea how to preserve the original frame rate of `29.970000`?

one file from original video:

```
Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf52.93.0
  Duration: 00:26:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6929 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6808 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 114 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

After concatenation (the full file):

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Duration: 01:50:53.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6944 kb/s
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6813 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 11988 tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 120 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Comment: Have you looked at the pretty well written [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)? For `-vsync vfr`, it says "Frames are passed through with their timestamp or dropped so as to prevent 2 frames from having the same timestamp." Depending on your input, you might be losing frames. Also, many AAC encoders introduce padding so your audio might be longer than the video in each segment, introducing all sorts of av-sync problems. Can you check your input for those pitfalls?

Comment: What do you mean by checking the input? The inpute frame rate is 29.970000 as reported by VLC. When I do an `ffprobe input.mp4` both the `fps` and `tbs` values are `29.97` as well.

Comment: Do the files contain frames with overlapping presentation timestamps? Is the audio longer than the video?

Comment: How can I figure that out? I updated my post with the ffprobe outputs of both the original file and the concatenated one. Since the original consist of multiple files, I only ffprobed one of originals.

Comment: The difference is 0.000026 or 1 fewer frame shown in 10.7 hours of playback. Not worth debugging. Most likely due to a micro timestamp adjustment in one of the further inputs due to a different timebase.